# Include Guards syntax in C

Tags: c, include

Hello everyone I want to ask a question about including **guards** in C programming. I know their purpose but in some programms I have seen a **1**" written after #define like this:

```
#ifndef MYFILE_H
#define MYFILE_H 1
```

What is the purpose of this **1**? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary if the `MYFILE_H` macro is not used elsewhere in your code.

If it is used elsewhere with an `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` directive like here:

```
#ifdef MYFILE_H
```

then the `1` is not required in the macro definition-

but it if it used elsewhere with an `#if` directive like here:

```
#if MYFILE_H
```

then the `1` (or any value `!= 0`) is required in the macro definition.

Note these directives could be used in a source file to verify if the header is included or not.

Comment: Sir does this also mean that we can use same named macro in both include guard and #if directive at the same time ? and differentiate by using only "1" or any number in include guard ?

Comment: @mainajaved a preprocessor directive in a source code can be used to check if the the header is included or not just by checking if the header guard macro is defined or not. If the header guard macro was defined with the `1`, it can be checked with both `#ifdef` or `#if` directive otherwise only with the `#ifdef` directive.

Comment: b-but why does it need it?

Answer (score 6):

It's not necessary, `#define MYFILE_H` should do the trick. The fact that `MYFILE_H` is **defined** (the condition tested by `ifndef`) is separated from its value. It could be 0, ' ', 42, etc.

Comment: Sir you mean that only #define MYFILE_H is sufficient than why this "1"

Comment: @mainajaved That's something the original author of the code can answer best. My personal guess - he/she thought it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's a style thing, as far as i know. That '1' is unnecessary in my opinion; it doesn't really do anything.