# Googletest compile fails on defining a struct in #imported file

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, googletest

I have two files, `first_pass.c` that includes `mystring.h` that describes `mystring.c`. While testing `first_pass.c` I did the following includes

```
#include "../src/mystring.c"
#include "../src/first_pass.c"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
```

Everything worked well, until I had to define a structure in `mystring.h`. Simple as that

```
typedef struct Split {
    char *head;
    char *tail;
}Split;
```

And then I started to fail while compiling on `error: ‘Split’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct Split Split’`

The requirements for the course are using **C** (not C++) and MAKE, so other testing frameworks, like Check were deprecated. I understand that it defines twice the struct, first time when it loads `mystring.c` and another on `first_pass.c`. What can I do about it?

Comment: Why are you defining the same structure twice ?

Comment: #including the source file (.c) is asking for trouble

Comment: As I answered below, I didn't had a choise. googletest files are simple headers with TEST macros, so to have the definition for my tested code I have to include it whole. This was my reference: http://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/unit-testing-c-code-with-the-googletest-framework/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use header guards to prevent the inclusion of headers more than once.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

one suggestion add header files to a `C` files not `C` files to another `C` file.

Comment: You're right! I've read about it, but didn't think that this is the case. Thank you! I'll give you the check because you were first.

Answer (score 2):

Best way: don't include '.c' files but compile then to seperate '.o' and link tem all together.

If multiply inclusion oh a header like `mystring.h` is unevitable, look for for header guards, for example [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915061/include-guards-syntax-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You need to guard your structure definition as below

```
#ifndef SOME_GUARD_NAME
#define SOME_GUARD_NAME

typedef struct Split {
    char *head;
    char *tail;
}Split;

#endif
```

Since you are including "`.c`" files so please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232693/including-one-c-source-file-in-another) to avoid all this mess.

Comment: I didn't had a choise. googletest files are simple headers with TEST macros, so to have definition for my tested code I have to include it whole. But thank you for a good educational link.